# building libav 12.3 using cygwin

Tags: cygwin, libav

I'm trying to build libav 12.3 from https://libav.org/download/ using cygwin on Windows 10. There is some documentation on the libav.org website: https://libav.org/documentation/platform.html#Compilation-under-Cygwin
but it is out of date.

*I want to know what cygwin packages I need to install.* For example, the website specifies texi2html, which I can't find anywhere. Additional libraries such as yasm are not listed.

Some kind of math library is also missing. Currently, my compilation is failing with:

> libavfilter/af_compand.c: In function ‘config_output’:
>   libavfilter/af_compand.c:343:43: error: ‘M_LN10’ undeclared (first use in this >function); did you mean ‘_M_LN2’?
>        double radius         = s->curve_dB * M_LN10 / 20.0;
>                                              ^~~~~~
>                                              _M_LN2

Answer (score 0):

`texi2html` is a cygwin package.

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/bin/texi2html
Found 2 matches for usr/bin/texi2html
texi2html-1.82-10 - texi2html: A highly customizable texinfo to HTML and other formats translator (installed binaries and support files)
texi2html-1.82-11 - texi2html: A highly customizable texinfo to HTML and other formats translator (installed binaries and support files)
```

To install it,  you need to follow 
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

M_LN10 is defined in "/usr/include/math.h"

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/include/math.h
Found 6 matches for usr/include/math.h
cygwin-devel-2.10.0-1 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin-devel-2.11.0-0.2 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
cygwin-devel-2.9.0-3 - cygwin-devel: Core development files
..
```

so you need to install the `cygwin-devel` package that includes the standard cygwin headers.